# React - FETCH method doesn't read my .json file

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I have an issue to fetch my data. The code below is not working. It's returning `null` however there's some data in that JSON file. If I enter a HTTP link with some JSON data it works but can't read a local file.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";

export default function DataComponent() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    async function fetchData() {
        const response = await fetch("./data");
        setData(await response.json());
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
    );
}
```

Tried to move it to different folders or change a path, nothing have worked yet.

Comment: try saving await responce.json() in a const and then send it to setData

Answer (score 2):

Place your `json` file in `public` folder and Try to use `fetch` again.

[image]

examples

```
fetch('./example.json')
```

---

```
fetch('example.json')
```

---

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function DataComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  async function fetchData() {
    // const response = await fetch("./example.json");
    const response = await fetch("example.json");
    setData(await response.json());
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>;
}
```

*Tested win 10 react 17.0.2*